# Can we use Dispose method without Implementing IDisposable Interface?

Tags: c#, idisposable

Can we use Dispose method without Implementing IDisposable Interface ?

Comment: You can name a method as `Dispose` and use it without any restrictions, but if you want `using()` syntax you have to implement `IDisposable`

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to implement `IDisposable`? Did you try compiling it before asking this question?

Comment: My questions was can we call Dispose method of IDisposable interface without implementing the interface. For example for Connection object we call Con.Dispose?

Answer (score 2):

You can name a method as `Dispose` and use it as an ordinary method without any restrictions:

```
public class MyClass {
  public void Dispose() {
    ...
  }
}
...

// using() emulation
MyClass m = null;

try {
  m = new MyClass();
  ...
}
finally {
  if (m != null)
    m.Dispose();
}
```

but if you want `using()` syntax you *have to* implement `IDisposable`:

```
  public class MyNextClass: IDisposable {
    protected virtual void Dispose(Boolean disposing) {
      ...
    }

    public void Dispose() {
      Dispose(true);
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);   
    }
  }
  ...
  // compare this with the using() emulation in the code above
  using (MyNextClass n = new MyNextClass()) {
    ...
  }
```

Anyway, even it's *possible* to name a method `Dispose` it's not a good practice to *surprize* (and finally irritate) *developers* (including you) who read your texts; so either *implement* `IDisposable` or find *some other name* for the method.

Answer (score 0):

Managed Objects are disposed automatically even if you do not implement `IDisposable`, IDisposable let you dispose which runtime won't dispose like files, open handles   unmanaged code components.

[Implementing a Dispose Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The pattern for disposing an object, referred to as a dispose pattern,
>   imposes order on the lifetime of an object. The dispose pattern is
>   used only for objects that access unmanaged resources, such as file
>   and pipe handles, registry handles, wait handles, or pointers to
>   blocks of unmanaged memory. This is because the garbage collector is
>   very efficient at reclaiming unused managed objects, but it is unable
>   to reclaim unmanaged objects.

If you do not want to use the IDisposable pattern and want to have your own then I believe that is not recommended way as it **one would have to discover that could be obvious using IDisposable.**

Answer (score 0):

Nobody will stop you from doing that but it is very poor design because everybody knows about the idisposable interface. If you give a different meaning to this method, you are obfuscating your design to whoever takes a look at your code later. Maybe even yourself in a few years where you don't remember the reason why you did this .